# Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Raspbian not booting

Tags: raspbian, boot-issues

Noob here.. Got the Raspberry Pi 3 model B a couple of weeks ago. Downloaded and installed the Raspbian linux onto a class 10 Micro SD card. Boots perfectly for the first time. But after I shut down, and turn on the Pi again, the text diagnostics appear, and that's it! Doesn't show the desktop. A small multi-colour square is seen on the top right side of the screen. Where am I going wrong?

Also, which is the best video player for this and how to install? Kindly help..

Thanks in Advance! :)

Comment: How are you powering the Pi and what is connected to it?

Comment: This is a quite  common situation.  I am disappointed Google didn't provide you with an answer.

Comment: Hi Steve. 

 I power it using a 5V 2A adapter and  connect my USB keyboard and wireless mouse's USB dongle.,....

Comment: That wall of text you see is normal, don't panic. Does the text reach a point where it asks for a username and password? If so, username is pi, password is raspberry. Then type in startx and hit enter, this loads the desktop. Then in Raspi-Config there is a setting which you can change so the Pi boots straight to the desktop.

Comment: Darth Vader it does not ask me anything.. It scrolls through the diagnosis then stays blank.. :)

Answer (score 1):

The "small multi-colour square … on the top right side of the screen" is an indicator that the Raspberry Pi is not getting enough power over the MicroUSB socket. This potentially could cause followup issues.

For the Raspberry Pi 3, a 2.5A power supply is recommended. (For the Raspberry Pi 2, a 2.0A power supply is said to suffice although a 2.1A power supply seems to be recommended.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Axel Beckert! :) Guess that answers my question. I'll try for a higher power source...